# Canonical form for $x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz$, using Gauss

Tags: gaussian-elimination

I need to find a canonical form for the following equation, throughout the Gauss method.

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz$$

And I'm stuck at this point, because even if I continue to creeate $(a+b+c)^2$ it seems to return same result:

$$(x+y+z)^2-xy-xz-yz$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to complete the square:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}(y+z)\right)^2+y^2+z^2-\frac{1}{4}(y+z)^2+yz.\\
=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}(y+z)\right)^2+\frac 3 4 y^2+\frac 3 4 z^2+\frac 1 2yz=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}(y+z)\right)^2+\frac 3 4\left(y+\frac1  3z\right)^2+\frac {2} {3}z^2.$$

Comment: It does not  lead to the canonical form

Comment: This's the Gauss's method, see this Wiki page: [Réduction de Gauss](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9duction_de_Gauss) *in French*.

Comment: Oh..yes, sorry..I mixed with the Gauss eliminations for linear eqations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Reduce  the equation 
$$
\left( ax+ay \right) ^{2}+ \left( bx+z \right) ^{2}+ \left( cy+c z \right) ^
{2}-{x}^{2}-{y}^{2}-{z}^{2}-xy-xz-yz=0
$$
to system of equations.

After solution  you will  get 
$$
\left(  \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}x+ \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}y \right) ^{2}+ \left(  \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}y+ \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}z \right) ^{2}+ \left(  \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}x+ \frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}z \right) ^{2}=\\={x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+{z}^{2}+xy+xz+yz
$$